# Catch a C++ unhandled exception in the signal handler and resume application

Tags: c++, c, exception, signals, posix

**First some context :**

I am testing the robustness of some C-written service, running in an embedded Linux. All my tests are written in C++ and invoke the C API of the service.

Note that the service and the application are running in 2 separate processes. The application opens a proxy within its context to communicate to the service over tcp/ip.

To check an ill-coded callback could not break the service, I am giving it a function which simply throws a C++ exception. As expected, throwing an exception within this C-callback is causing the application to crash.

The service appears so far to be robust to this : the callback is called from a thread which is running in the context of the client application. This means, only the client application is crashed, and the service remains alive.

When I say the application crashes, I mean that it receives a SIGABRT signal, here is the callstack from gdb :

```
(gdb) info stack
0  0x4c22cb94 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
1  0x4c230670 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
2  0xb6e9e6c4 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
3  0xb6e9c214 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
4  0xb6e9c288 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
5  0xb6e9c5ac in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
6  0x0011824c in LocationTest::crashingLocCb (location=<optimized out>)
at ../../../TestLibrary/200-Location/src/locationtest.cpp:427
7  0x00144f64 in locationCb (location=<optimized out>)
at ../../PAL/src/tms/pallocationprovider.cpp:109
8  0xb6fbdb50 in locationcallback_thread (thread_info=0x1a82b8)
at ../lib_c/src-gen/location_proxy.c:273
9  0x4c33defc in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
```

**What I would like to do now :**

I want to catch the signal SIGABRT and resume the test application, to go further (check service has not some internal state broken ; check it has not caused some leak etc.. )

What would be the best approach to have something as clean as possible ?

This is to be done with the signal handler, but then would the other running threads be harmed ? what is the best method then to send back the information caught in the signal handler to the relevant thread ?

(I have yet not much experience with those posix signals)

Comment: `**still writing, please wait **` What is that supposed to mean? Please provide complete questions, not work in progress. SO is not your scratch-pad!

Comment: I'm guessing, that the OP is still writing, but I'm not sure

Comment: I had to switch computer since gdb traces were on the linux machine ;)

Comment: done. you can remove your downvote I guess

Comment: *"To check an ill-coded callback could not break the service, I am giving it a function which simply throws a C++ exception."* - you can not check this. *"As expected, throwing an exception within this C-callback is causing the application to crash."* - throwing exception within C-callback leaves program in inconsistent state because C language does not have a concept of exceptions. So it will be just a random roller coaster. Also if crash happens in thread which is running in the context of the client application then entire process crashes, not just that thread.

Comment: If you want your program to be resilient to crashes in client applicatiios, you pretty much must run said applications as separate processes. At which point it becomes irrelevant what language(s) they are written in. They are totally isolated.

Comment: Indeed the service and the test application are running in 2 different processes. They communicate over a tcp/ip protocol. So when the signal SIGABRT is raised and not caught, only the test application process is killed.

Comment: edited my question to add this later comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem (in pseudocode). There were probably other ways, I'm still all ears opened :

```
void malfunction()
{

    terminate_handler previousTerminateHandler = set_terminate(callbackUnhandledExceptionTerminateHandler);

    registerCallback(throwingCb);
    launchTheTest();
    waitForErrorEvent();
    saveTheResult();
    doSomeCleanUp();

    set_terminate(previousTerminateHandler);

    return;
}

static void callbackUnhandledExceptionTerminateHandler()
{
    try{ throw; }
    catch(const exception& e) { 
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        notifyTheErrorEvent();
    }catch(...){
        cout << "callbackUnhandledExceptionTerminateHandler : else ???" << endl;
        abort();
    }

    //Log whatever information, you need such as pid, stack or whatever
    cout << "processId = " << getpid() << endl;

    //Here if you return from this handler, it will call abort();
    //You could let it ends, if you already logged what you needed.
    //You could also trap the thread, if this is something you already do elsewhere before stopping the application.
```

}

In my case, I could check the service would be resilient to a crash of the customer application, and still be able to let other (or even the same!) open another proxy and do more work. Now left to do is to make sure no memory leak is caused here. (only to answer to whom would question why all this).

In a more general case, this same handling could be used to print the stack upon unhandled exception, without the need of gdb.

Comment: accepting my own answer since no other proposition cames out